# How to kill a key triggered process?

Tags: bash, process, signals

I wrote a bash script, and assigned a keyboard shortcut to trigger the same. Once I hit the shortcut keys, I have no control over it. I want to be able to kill it while it is running. How do I do it?

The problem is that the script takes over key and mouse control, so I cannot start/switch to the terminal while it is running to find the PID and send it a signal.

Comment: this is not a duplicate as OP mention "I cannot start a terminal", I assume OP would find pid using ps.

Comment: I do not have ssh running

Comment: @HardikKhane Is the script running on a Linux OS? Can you switch to a virtual terminal, via ctrl+alt+F6 or such? If yes, then that would be a way to have a 2nd terminal, to list processes and kill as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote another script that kills all the processes(instances) of the original script, and assigned a keyboard shortcut to it. This way once script A is triggered with a key combination, I can kill it instantly with another key combination without the hassle of switching between windows; thereby avoiding messing up things.

Thanks for the the support and ideas though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Running the script within `screen` or `tmux` may help.

If not then you could write a script which kills this process (if it is running) and activate this script via `udev` when a certain USB device is attached.

Comment: I start the process which works on the GUI by pressing a key combination, and I want to stop it the same way, as the process itself makes mouse clicks, and switching to terminal or any other window messes up things.

Comment: @HardikKhane Maybe it is best to run the process not in your usual environment but with a virtual X server or even in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Have two terminals running, same user.

One terminal is running the script

The second terminal is to monitor, using `top` or `ps aux`, and to kill the process from the other terminal, as necessary.

Comment: I start the process which works on the GUI by pressing a key combination, and I want to stop it the same way, as the process itself makes mouse clicks, and switching to terminal or any other window messes up things.